# XSLT How to the get first node of match

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a XML like this one:

```
<a>
  <b attribute="yes" />
  <c attribute="yes" />
  <c attribute="yes" />
</a>
```

How can I get the first node of this match:

```
a/c[@attribute = 'yes']/../b[@attribute='yes' or @attribute='no']
```

I tried to add `[1]` at the end of my expression but it does not really work because when there are several `<c attribute="yes" />` then I get several `<b>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can re-write your expression like this...

```
a[c[@attribute = 'yes']]/b[@attribute='yes' or @attribute='no']
```

This means you can get the first one like this

```
a[c[@attribute = 'yes']]/b[@attribute='yes' or @attribute='no'][1]
```

Of course, this assumes there are not multiple `a` elements (i.e `a` is not actually the root element). In which case, you could write this...

```
(a[c[@attribute = 'yes']]/b[@attribute='yes' or @attribute='no'])[1]
```

Comment: Sorry, I edited my expression. Actually I want to get the `<b />`.

Answer (score 1):

> I tried to add `[1]` at the end of my expression but it does not really
>   work

I am not sure what you want either, but adding `[1]` at the end of your expression **does** seem to work. If we change the **input** to :

```
<a>
  <b attribute="yes"  />
  <c attribute="yes" id="1"/>
  <c attribute="yes" id="2"/>
</a>
```

then:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy-of select="a/c[@attribute = 'yes']/../c[@attribute='yes' or @attribute='no'][1]"/>
</xsl:template>
```

returns:

```
<c attribute="yes" id="1"/>
```

Perhaps you should edit your question and explain in simple, non-technical language what is it that you're trying to achieve here.

---

### Edit

In response to your edit: it should still work. Using the following input:

```
<a>
  <b attribute="yes" id="1" />
  <c attribute="yes" id="2"/>
  <c attribute="yes" id="3"/>
  <b attribute="yes" id="4" />
</a>
```

this instruction:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="a/c[@attribute = 'yes']/../b[@attribute='yes' or @attribute='no'][1]"/>
```

returns:

```
<b attribute="yes" id="1"/>
```

Comment: Sorry, I edited my expression. Actually I want to get the `<b />`.

Comment: @charles See the edit to my answer. I suggest again you explain what you're really after, as it seems that the expression is unduly complex.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `a/b/c[1]`, you want `(a/b/c)[1]`. Otherwise the `[1]` applies only to the last step in the path, it selects the first `c` of every `a/b`.